# How to integrate Nicepage site on Joomla

Tags: plugin, development, joomla-api, integration, simplecrm

I am kinda new to this whole website thing. Definatly dont have much experiance in coding ect, but I have created a whole website with a nicepage paid subscription. I downloaded Joomla and XAMPP. I have tried to import my site several times but nothing seems to change in Joomla. Also don't understand the menu options for Joomla. I guess all around i'm just lost with Joomla. Is there anyone that can help?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ask a question showing what you have done as per community rules.

Given your current question, I suggest you [familiarize yourself with Joomla](https://www.joomla.org/about-joomla/getting-started.html)

Then (provided this is what you meant, your "question" is quite obscure) learn about the extension you are using: [this](https://nicepage.com/doc/70240/install-joomla-extension) is a first result on a web search

Finally, if you are still stuck, get in touch with the above mentioned extension's developers.

Should this approach still leave you clueless, please come back here, explain the steps that you took, provide some examples of your failed attempts, and you might get some guidance.